# python: copying list and appending in one step

Tags: list, python-2.7, list-comprehension, copying

I have a strange reaction of python (using 2.7) here. I am trying to copy a list and append something to the copy at the same time. Here is the code:

```
myList = [1]
>>> newList = list(myList).append(2)
>>> newList
>>> print newList
None
>>> type(newList)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Why is it that I get a NoneType object instead of my appended list-copy?
I stumbled over this when I tried to take a list1 copy it as many times as a list2 and append the elements of list2 to the ones in list1.

```
>>> list1 = [1,2]
>>> list2 = [3,4]
>>> list3 = [list(list1).append(i) for i in list2]
>>> list3
[None, None]
```

I expected:

```
>>> list3
[[1,2,3],[1,2,4]]
```

Why is it None,None?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Bcz list.append() return NoneType object....thats why u r getting nonetype....

Comment: Thanks, but why? I am giving list() a list, so shoulded this create another list, which then should be appendable?

Comment: No it will give NoneType again u can check it by place the  object in 'type()' ....

Answer (score 0):

**You can do  this by adding a extra line:**

```
myList=[1]
myList.append(2);newList=myList
```

**You can also extend (append )list directly like:**

```
list1 = [1,2]
list2 = [3,4]
list1.extend(list2);list3=list1
```

**If u dont want to alter then try this:**

```
list1 = [1,2]
list2 = [3,4]
list3=list1;list3.extend(list2)
```

**And also:**

```
myList=[1]
newList=myList;newList.append(2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that I need to copy the first list, as I will take it as the base for many other lists, so I cannot just alter the original list.

Comment: Thanks but that does not work. In Python variable names are only pointers to an object. If I set list1 = list2 they point to the same object. By altering one, I alter both. Thats why I wanted to copy with list(list1) or list[:].

Answer (score 0):

The append function modifies a list and returns None.  Newlist was None because append() modifies the list directly, rather than returning the modified list.
This code will create the new list and add to it in one step.

```
myList = [1]
newList = myList + [2]
```